# web scraping using selenium in python

Tags: python, html, selenium

i want to scrape data from this site https://loschmidt.chemi.muni.cz/predictsnp2/ but i am having problem obtaining text from the table after pressing the button through my code. i don't know what i am doing wrong because it is my first doing it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = 
Webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='D:\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe ')
url = "https://loschmidt.chemi.muni.cz/predictsnp2/"
driver . get( url )
s = driver.find_element_by_id ( "isc_3I" )
st="6,1613076,A,T \n1,66075952,G,C \n1,201328373,G,A \n18,48575659,A,G 
    \n3,37067050,A,G"
s1 = driver.find_element_by_id ( 'isc_2S' )
s2 = driver.find_element_by_id ( 'isc_37' )
st1 = 'GRCh38.p1 '
s1 . send_keys ( st1 )
s2 . send_keys ( 'Simple' ) 
s . send_keys ( st )
driver . find_element_by_xpath ( '//div[@id="isc_4B"]' )
time . sleep ( 20 )
print ( driver . find_element_by_xpath ( '//div[@id="isc_4X"]' ) . text )
driver . quit()
```

C:\Users\kakkakksfssdsf\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/kakkakksfssdsf/PycharmProjects/untitled/test.py

Load file :

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Did you try to debug the application?

Comment: What is the expected outcome? Is `exit code 0` the only error you get? Please refer to the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of asking great questions.

Comment: yes the only that i am getting is  exit code 0. Actually i want to click the button but it is not a button but a data cell inside a division. That is why nothing is showing. could you explain me how click that data cell.

Comment: yes i have debugged my code. nothing is showing because the button i am trying to click is a <div> inside which is <td> and inside it there is another <div>.